# PHP Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare() Wordpress 3.5

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi am am getting the error message:

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /home/url.com/wp-content/plugins/WPEC-Personalize-3.8/wpec-personalization.php on line 322 and defined in /home/url.com/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 990
```

I have found the code on line 322:

```
$add = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT enabled FROM ". $table_name ." WHERE pers_id  = ". $myresults->pers_id." AND product_id = ".$product_id));
```

I am trying to update it to the new wordpress standard:

```
$add = $wpdb->get_var$wpdb->prepare("SELECT enabled FROM . %d . WHERE pers_id  = . %d. AND product_id = .%s",$table_name, $myresults->pers_id, $product_id));
```

Im not sure what im missing. Unfortunately im not the author of this plugin and he is not planing any updates :-(.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Ditch the periods.  Also missing the opening bracket for `get_var`

```
$add = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT enabled FROM %s WHERE pers_id = %d AND product_id = %d",
    $table_name, 
    $myresults->pers_id, 
    $product_id
));
```

Comment: I have added the code below and stopped receiving the error message (HURRAY) but every time i update the product it duplicates the custom fields it generating. Any idea why?

Comment: I would have to see the full code to be certain of what is going on.

Comment: Is there a way i could paste the php file somewhere for you to take a look?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$add = $wpdb->get_var$wpdb->prepare("SELECT enabled FROM . %d . WHERE pers_id  = . %d. AND product_id = .%s",$table_name, $myresults->pers_id, $product_id));
```

Seems to be missing brackets, and the query has a bunch of periods in it that I'm pretty sure shouldn't be there.

```
$add = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT enabled FROM %d WHERE pers_id  = %d AND product_id = %s",$table_name, $myresults->pers_id, $product_id));
```

Also, I'm not a *pro* in Wordpress's back end, but it seems to be using `sprintf()` syntax in the query, and `%d` indicates a decimal number which is probably not super good for a table name.

Anyhow, you should probably contact the plugin's author for support as to what should actually be going on in the code if the plugin stopped working for the current version.

Comment: I have added the code below and stopped receiving the error message (HURRAY) but every time i update the product it duplicates the custom fields it generating. Any idea why?